# How to test PKI signature verification algorithm

Tags: java, testing, signature, pki

What's your test setup for PKI signature verification?
Where did you get test documents for broken signatures?
If you created them by yourself, how did you go about and what tools did you use to produce maligned signatures?

The signing algorithm in question is PKCS#7 detached (within PDFs)

Answer (score 1):

I felt like coming back to this, telling you how we dealt with the issue.

We got two or three valid samples and one with expired Root CA. We were not able to get any sample with a revoked certificate - neither the Root CA nor our business partner, who is issuing the documents in question, could supply is with any OCSP/CRL sample.

We only implemented PKCS#7 detached validation as business requirements were as such. As we were working with Java and signed PDFs, we went for iText as it turned out to do most of the work.

We looked at Bouncy Castle before going to iText. Bouncy Castle turned out to be detailed on a level we could not work with. And you should never do crypto on your own, especially in certain sensitive work environments - or really just never.

We went into production without being able to test for certain cases. We are fairly certain we caught them, but I guess we might never know.

Why is it so difficult to get test cases for the most commonly used cryptography?